# MarkLogic node.js api - group by and sort by count

Tags: node.js, marklogic

In a relational db you'd have something like "select name, count(1) as c from mytable group by name order by c desc". Basically I want to count how many records contain each name value and get the ones with highest counts first.

Is there a way to do a similar thing in Marklogic using the Node.js API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var marklogic = require('marklogic');
var my = require('./my-connection.js');

var db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(my.connInfo);
var vb = marklogic.valuesBuilder;

db.values.read(
  vb.fromIndexes('name')
    .withOptions({values: ['descending', 'frequency-order']});
```

The [Querying Lexicons and Range Indexes section](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/search#id_56768) of the Node.js Application Developer's Guide will provide more detail.

Comment: the values: descending option seems to have just sorted by name (descending). I want to be able to sort by frequency, is it possible?

Comment: After some mucking around in the documentation, I found that I just have to use .withOptions({values: ['descending', 'frequency-order']}). I'll accept this as correct, but it might be useful to have this info in the answer itself. Thanks!