# MarkLogic node.js api - group by sum

Tags: node.js, marklogic

Something similar to my question here: [MarkLogic node.js api - group by and sort by count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715822/marklogic-node-js-api-group-by-and-sort-by-count)

I have documents in Marklogic with fields *name* and *amount*. I want to get the total amount for each name. Basically in SQL it would be

```
select name, sum(amount) from table group by name
```

I have **range indexes** for both *name* and *amount*.
 For getting sum aggregates, the documentation suggests something like **valuesBuilder.fromIndexes('amount').aggregates('sum')**, but this only gets the sum for all records, instead of per name like I want.

Any advice?

Comment: can you show a sample document? I assume that you have the same name appear in different documents with different URIs - is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to Dave's suggestion you can do something similar in Node.js but again, the work/code would have to be developed by you.

Option 1)

```
db.values.read(
  vb.fromIndexes('name', 'amount')
)
.result()
```

this code here creates a value co-occurance of names and amounts - you can then go and process this information.

Option 2)

Get the names from the indexes, then feed that information to another function that would get the amounts and sum them up:

```
function getNames() {
  return db.values.read(
    vb.fromIndexes('name')
  )
  .result();
}

function getSum(names) {
  const promises = names.map(name => {
     return db.values.read(
      vb.fromIndexes('amount')
      .aggregates('sum')
      .where(vb.parsedFrom(`name:${name}`,
             vb.parseBindings(vb.value('name', vb.bind('name')))
    ))).result();
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
};

getNames()
.then(response => {
  const names = response['values-response'].tuple.map(name => name['distinct-value'].toString());
  console.log(names); //this will hold all the names
  return getSum(names);
})
.then(response => {
  const sums = response.map(r => {
    return r['values-response']['aggregate-result'][0];
  }).map(s => s._value);
  console.log(sums); //this will hold all the sums
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Option 3)

What Dave suggested - create the SJS extension, and call that from Node.js

Comment: I liked the idea of using an extension because there's no way around this being a 2-stage query. With an extension, the Node.js tier will make one (HTTP) call and the response data will consist of just the final result. Option #1 here is only one call, but with unconsolidated data; option #2 will make several calls. The advantage here is the all the relevant code is in one place (the Node.js tier).

Comment: I'll accept this one because I basically went ahead and did option #1. I'm a bit disappointed in Marklogic that there isn't out of the box group-by-and-aggregate support though, as that seems a really common use case when looking at large stacks of documents that have some financial information inside

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an out-of-the-box group by, but you can build an extension to do it. I made some sample docs like this:

```
declareUpdate();

for (let index=0; index < 1000; index++) {
  xdmp.documentInsert(
    '/values' + index + '.json',
    {
      "name": "val" + (xdmp.random(2) + 1),
      "amount": xdmp.random(2) + 1
    }
  )
}
```

I ran this code in Query Console:

```
'use strict';

var jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch.sjs');
var tuples = 
  jsearch.tuples(
    [
      cts.jsonPropertyReference('name'), 
      cts.jsonPropertyReference('amount', ["type=int"])
    ]
  )
    .slice(0, 1000) // get all the values
    .map({frequency: "item", names: ['name', 'count', 'frequency']})
    .result();

tuples
  .reduce(function(acc, current, index, array) {
    acc[current.name] = parseInt(current.count, 10) * current.frequency;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

That got me a response of:

```
{
  "val1": 381, 
  "val2": 351, 
  "val3": 324
}
```

I think that's what you're looking for. Other stuff you'll need:

- [docs on creating a REST extension](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions#id_21018)
- [calling a REST extension from the Node.js Client API](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/node-dev/extensions#id_66908)
- and you'll need range indexes on `name` (string) and `count` (int).

Answer (score 1):

One footnote to the good suggestions from Tamas and Dave -- in MarkLogic 9, you can use the Optic API in ways similar to the following example (in this case, using Server-Side JavaScript):

```
'use strict';
const op = require('/MarkLogic/optic');

const employees = op.fromView(null, 'employees');
const expenses  = op.fromView(null, 'expenses');
employees
   .joinInner(expenses, op.on(
       employees.col('EmployeeID'), expenses.col('EmployeeID')
       ))
   .groupBy('LastName', op.sum('Total', 'Amount'))
   .orderBy('Total')
   .where(op.lt(199, op.col('Total')))
   .result();
```